# How to share a single /home/ directory between different OS?

Tags: linux

I just installed Devuan on a laptop in dualboot with Arch Linux.

I would like to share the same `/home/myuser` between these two distributions, so in `/etc/fstab` I added a line for `/home` with the same UUID as in Arch Linux.

But I am not able to connect on Devuan with myuser. I've already done this on other PCs with no issue. What am I doing wrong?

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=1005964,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=808196k,mode=755)
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=3271160k)
/dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
```

============
Author of the question made this answer:

I created a password for myuser and i am now able to login.

```
#passwd myuser
```

Thank you all.

Fabien
EDIT: please forget this and check the last answer.

Comment: Bonjour Fabien, can you edit and paste the result of the `mount`command from Devuan ?

Comment: Where should I answer you?

Comment: Are the user IDs the same on both systems? For example, do you have a user named *myuser* with ID 1234 on both systems?

Comment: What does "not able to connect" mean?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa : the uid is the same, 1000. But gid and groups are different.

Comment: @symcbean: I meant "not able to login"

Comment: Please don't do this; config files between different linux system can act differently. Instead share the user content in /home/$USER/. See `~./config/user-dirs.dirs` See https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/

Comment: Ok, thank you, now i understand it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

It might be the case that, even if your /home/ is mounted correctly if your user is not the owner of the home directory login would fail. It might be that even with the same username they have different uid.

The easy way I see for fixing your issue is log in as root, ensure that the correct /home/ has been mounted and make sure that `username` is the owner of everything on /home/username by recursively chowning it:

```
chown -R username:usergroup /home/username/*
```

After finishing try to log in again as `username`, now it should work.

Now, you also mentioned that you added to /etc/fstab the /home/ partition(or disk) with the UUID it had on Arch. Are you 100% sure it's the same Devuan is calculating? Double check it with:

```
lsblk -f
```

or

```
blkid
```

Comment: Better yet, make sure the uids on the 2 systems match - edit /etcpasswd and /etc/shadow (with vipw) and descide on a common uid to use for user,  change the files, on all the instances then chmod the files.

Comment: Thank you jordi, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes the UUID is the same for both OSes.

Answer (score 1):

As a word of warning... some apps with different versions have different config file options and unknown options could either break the application, corrupt the config, or just be removed when the app exits.  For this reason alone I'd be wary of sharing your ~/ (all those ~/.foo files).

What does work is to have a 3rd partition where you link in your Documents, Downloads, Desktop, etc. directories so that content at least is available in both systems.

Comment: Thank you for warning me, it was obviously not a good idea...Thank you to share you knowledge :)